# Lint: Call to function 'memcpy(void *, const void *, std::size_t)' violates semantic '(3n>4)'

Tags: c++, lint

This is a part of my code base .
I am not getting the meaning of warning and so am not able to resolve this ...
code :

```
struct ParamsTube{
    uint8                Colours01[4];
    uint8                Colours02[4];
    uint8                Colours03[4];
};

void sample_fun(const uint8 *diagData){
    ParamsTube Record;
    memcpy(&Record.Colours01[0], &diagData[0], 4); //Line 1
    memcpy(&Record.Colours02[0], &diagData[4], 4); //Line 2
    memcpy(&Record.Colours03[0], &diagData[8], 4); //Line 3
}
```

and LINT warning 426 for this logic at line 1,2 and 3 is

```
Call to function 'memcpy(void *, const void *, std::size_t)' violates semantic '(3n>4)'
```

Can you tell me what exactly it means .....

Comment: You are copying the same value into all the colour variables. The source is always `&diagData[0]`. Did you mean `&diagData[0]`, `&diagData[4]` and `&diagData[8]`?

Comment: sorry ..i have modified properly ..its coping frm diagdata[0],1 and 2 ...this is modified in above..now for this code base i am getting the warning ..

Comment: @MariusBancila,should the index be multiple of 4 ????

Comment: As side note, I would use sizeof( uint8 ).

Comment: @IssamTP,I want num =4 as the size_t variable instead of sizeof( uint8 )...

Comment: Oh, well. Anyway I tried on my VS2010 and I'm not getting your warning with your code.

Comment: Am I correct in thinking this is a message from lint rather than the compiler?

Comment: @harmic,its true ..it is lint warning ..so I tag lint in my question ..Warning 426

Comment: Maybe you need `diagData[0]` instead of `&diagData[0]`. Not sure because don't see all code, but you can even try `diagData + 0`

Comment: @MariusBancila..sorry ..it is indexed  as you mentioned in your comment ...Sorry its my mistake only ....

Comment: Lint is talking out of its ***. The code is fine as is; just suppress this broken warning.

Answer (score 7):

`(3n > 4)` means the third argument used to call `memcpy()` should be larger than 4, and your calls violate this semantic.  The semantic seems to state that `memcpy()` shouldn't be used to copy data smaller than a machine word (usually 4).  That's why lint is warning you.  Whether the semantic is appropriate or not is another question.

---

Below is the explanation of lint warning 426:

> 426   Call to function 'Symbol' violates semantic 'String' -- This Warning message is issued when a user semantic (as defined by -sem) is violated.  'String' is the subportion of the semantic that was violated.  For example:

```
//lint -sem( f, 1n > 10 && 2n > 10 )  
        void f( int, int );  
        ...  
        f( 2, 20 );
```

results in the message:

```
Call to function 'f(int, int)' violates semantic '(1n>10)'
```

So the `memcpy()` in your environment probably has a leading lint semantic like this:

```
// lint -sem(memcpy, 3n > 4)
void* memcpy(void* s1, const void* s2, std::size_t n);
```

---

For your case, if what you want to achieve is actually:

```
memcpy(&Record.Colours01[0], &diagData[0], 4); //Line 1
memcpy(&Record.Colours02[1], &diagData[4], 4); //Line 2
memcpy(&Record.Colours03[2], &diagData[8], 4); //Line 3
```

then simply:

```
memcpy(&Record, diagData, sizeof(Record));
```

will do all the work without triggering the lint warning.

Comment: as in mentioned memcpy function third argument is 4 ..so it is equal to 4 and the condition (3n>4 ) ..How is not satisfied ?

Comment: @Ashwin: The third argument 4 is equal to 4, but not larger than 4, so the requirement `(3n > 4)` is not satisfied.  `3n` designates the third argument.

Comment: As per my algorithm ..it should be 4 ..not more than 4 ..so how should I resolve this warning ??

Comment: +1... faster and more complete than mine. I just add [this reference](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Object-Size-Checking.html), where it states that it can perform some checks at compile time with memcpy-like intrinsics.

Comment: to copy 4 bytes I would you just use "="... `*(uint4 *)&dest = *(uint4 *)&source;`

Comment: @Sigismondo ,error: identifier "uint4" is undefined

Comment: *((uint32_t*)&Record.Colours01[0]) = *((uint32_t*)&diagData[0]);                                                                       Is it copying only 4 byte ?????

Comment: @neverhoodboy ,with your logic also it is not yet resolved ..still giving same warning for that line of code ......  :(

Comment: This is a horrible Lint rule; `memcpy` is way superior than the ugly pointer casts in the replacement. Your original code is perfect; don't let any broken tools tell you otherwise.

Comment: @neverhoodboy ,these are the warnings after modification :             Info 1773: Attempt to cast away const (or volatile)
Info 826: Suspicious pointer-to-pointer conversion (area too small)

Answer (score 1):

Lint is telling you that you shouldn't call `memcpy` for 4 or fewer bytes.

This is idiotic.

Modern compilers know `memcpy` for what it is. If you compile with optimizations on GCC or Clang, at least, you will find that on x86, in the generated code the 4-byte `memcpy` has been replaced by a single `mov`. (Well, possibly two `mov`s when copying from memory to memory.)

The way you've written this code is the only portable, safe way to write it short of writing the byte copies one by one. In particular, writing this code is not portable:

```
*((uint32_t*)&Record.Colours01[0]) = *((uint32_t*)&diagData[0]);
```

This will work on x86, but only because that platform allows misaligned accesses. But if `diagData[0]` isn't aligned to a 4-byte boundary (and there's absolutely no reason to assume it would be), that's a misaligned access, and may well trigger a trap on other platforms (ARM has an alignment-checking mode; IA-64 and the late Alpha don't support unaligned access at all, as do various embedded chips).

For that matter, you can't even assume that `Colours01` is aligned. There's really no binding reason that the compiler should align it; additional variables on the stack may well push it out of alignment.

The `memcpy` is safe no matter what the alignment is, while giving the compiler the opportunity to optimize it to whatever it thinks is most efficient (e.g. `mov` on x86, where unaligned accesses are safe, and probably still faster than the alternative).

Lint complaining about this is a grave mistake on the authors of either Lint or the annotation on `memcpy`. Either way, you should not follow this rule; it leads to worse code.